# Javascript function with modulo

Tags: javascript, modulo

I ask to users to give a number `X` between 3 and 10.
I have to draw a line of 100 "_" and replace each `"_"` every `X` number.

If `X = 3` we have to see in the console:

```
___ # ___ # ___ # ___ # ___ # ___ # ___ # ___ # ___ # ___ # ___ # ___ #
```

I'm totally lost! I'm sure I have to use modulo but I don't know how.

Here is my code:

```
var number = prompt( "Saisissez un nombre entre 3 et 10" );
var line = "";

for ( var i = 0; i <= 100; i++ ) {

        line += "_";

if (line = line % number){

}
}

console.log(line);
```

Comment: You are on a good way... try to google for `length` in javascript and use `==` in your if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm late here. but if you don't want `#` at `0` index. You can skip it by adding one more `if`.

```
  var number = prompt( "Saisissez un nombre entre 3 et 10" );
  var line = "";
  for ( var i = 0; i <= 100; i++ ) {
      if(i!=0)
      if (i % number === 0)
          line += "#";
      else
          line += "_";
   }
   console.log(line); // Output: ____#____#____#____#____#____#____#____#____#____#____#____#____#____#____#____#____#____#____#____#
```

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it:

You just need to check the *index* of the loop against the user number and if its modulo is equal to zero, add the hash mark, otherwise, add an underscore instead:

```
var line = "";
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  if (i % number === 0) {
    line += "#";
  } else {
    line += "_";
  }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wg9auxtj/1/)

Comment: if I want an aleatory number, how can I use Math.random in this function?